# R Function To Calculate Accuracy at Threshold

Tags: r, function

```
DATA = read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
MODEL =  glm(admit ~ gre + gpa + rank, data = DATA, family = "binomial")

ACTUAL = DATA$admit
PRED = predict(MODEL, type = "response")

HAVE = data.frame(ACTUAL = ACTUAL, PRED = PRED)
```

I fit my model and store the ACTUAL and PRED values in HAVE which gives a data frame containing the real values and also the model prediction values.

To calculate model accuracy I have to convert PRED values into 0 and 1s and I can do that at different levels for example if PRED < .1, then 0 else 1. Then I can compare accuracy. I am wondering, how can I to do this calculation if I wish to transcribe the accuracy at a bunch of levels, say `CHECK = seq(0,1,.05)` ?

For example I can do this manually but how is there a function and efficient way to do so?

```
HAVE$PRED05 = with(HAVE, ifelse(PRED < .05,0,1))
with(HAVE, table(ACTUAL,PRED05))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own function pretty easily. We can add some checks and vectorize it like this

```
evaluate <- Vectorize(function(data, cutoff) {
  stopifnot(cutoff >= 0 & cutoff <= 1)
  stopifnot(all(c('ACTUAL','PRED') %in% names(data)))
  pred <- ifelse(data$PRED < cutoff, 0 , 1)
  table(data$ACTUAL, pred, dnn=list("actual", paste0("pred (", cutoff, ")")))
}, "cutoff")
```

By using Vectorize, we can pass in multiple check values at once. For example

```
CHECK = seq(0,1,.05)
evaluate(HAVE, CHECK)
```

will return a list of all the tables.

There are packages that can help with this stuff. For example the `ROCR` package. You can compare the accuracy for difference cutoff values.

```
library(ROCR)
pred <- with(HAVE, prediction(PRED, ACTUAL))
plot(performance(pred, "acc"))
```

See the `?performance` help page for a bunch of other metrics you can compare with.
[image]